# Enable HTTPS in IIS to access WEB API methods in Client Side

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssl, iis, asp.net-web-api, iis-7

We have developed an WEB API application by enabling HTTPS requests and deployed the same in a different machine in IIS. But when we try to call the WEB API methods in our MVC application we're actually getting the error and unable to connect either through the postman. When we're requesting through http, it's working but not using https.

Comment: Run a report and the cause should be clear, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html

Comment: Can you show me your error messages?

Comment: Here is the below code we tried calling the api and getting the error.

 public static void GetStudentData()
 {
       using (var client = new HttpClient())
       {
          var response = client.GetAsync("https://127.0.0.2:443/api/student").Result;
          if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
          {
                    Console.WriteLine(response);
          }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
}

Error : WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

Comment: Most likely because the SSL certificate is not trusted, please check your the SSL certificate's root certificate.